# постоянно крашится Unreal Engine 4.25.1

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Скачал недавно Unreal Engine 4. Как только создаю или открываю проект (даже пустой) (для разработки игр) открывается нормально не лагает, но через несколько секунд/минут (даже когда я ничего не делаю) он виснет. Сначала виснет сам анриал а потом и весь ноут так что даже диспетчер не открывается, приходится перезагружать кнопкой Power. Ноут по параметрам подходит (12 оперативки, geforce 1050, i5-8300H 2.3 GHz)

Что пробовал:

1. Менял IDE по умолчанию (думал может вижуалка грузит)
2. Запускал от админа (и не от админа тоже). + Савил галку отключить оптимизацию на весь екран как в гайдах в гугле.
3. Переустанавлявал
4. Ставил раннюю версию (Может попробовать скачать более более ранние? но качать и так уже надоело все равно не работает)
5. Ставил галку чтобы принудительно запускалось через видюху
6. Обновлял дрова
7. Нажимал *проверить* в лаунчере епиков

Comment: Проверьте ноут на перегрев CPU или видеокарты. Почистите от пыли.

Comment: @Kromster при вылете проц 64 градуса. Проблема решилась при открытии редактора не на полный экран

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась при открытии редактора не на полный экран